# Múltiples llamadas AJAX en formulario HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Tengo una página con un formulario. La página tiene un link al script de `JQuery`, y el código `AJAX` es el siguiente:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
                //Llamada AJAX 1
                function ajax_call_1(val)
                {
                 $.ajax({
                 type: 'post',
                 url: 'AJAX/fetch_data_index_1.php',
                 data: {
                  get_option:val
                 },
                 success: function (response) {
                  document.getElementById("select_edificios").innerHTML=response;
                 }
                 });
                }

                //Llamada AJAX 2
                function ajax_call_2(val_2)
                {
                 $.ajax({
                 type: 'post',
                 url: 'AJAX/fetch_data_index_2.php',
                 data: {
                  data_1:val_2
                 },
                 success: function (response) {
                  document.getElementById("update_edificios").innerHTML=response;
                 }
                 });
                }
                </script>
```

VAL viene de:

```
<select name="obra_nueva" onchange="ajax_call_1(this.value);">
```

VAL_2 viene de:

```
<tr id="select_edificios" onchange="ajax_call_2(this.value);">
```

CÓDIGO DE `fetch_data_index_2.php`

```
    $user = $_COOKIE['login_user'];
    $state = $_POST['data_1'];

    $sql ="update clientes set edificio_seleccionado=".$state." where dni_cliente='".$user."'";
    $conn = pg_connect("host='localhost' dbname='inmo_postgresql' port='5432' user='".$user."' password='password'") or die ("Error");
    echo "$sql";
    $result_sql = pg_query($conn,$sql) or die ("error");
```

La primera función de `AJAX` `(ajax_call_1)` funciona perfectamente, pero en la segunda, no me detecta el `"data_1"`.

Me ha parecido raro que haciendo la segunda función igual que la primera no funcione, y he pensado que el problema puede estar en que sólo se puede guardar el data de 1 función.

Comment: Como mandas llamar la funcion 2 de ajax?

Comment: La mando llamar con lo siguiente: <tr id="select_edificios" onchange="ajax_call_2(this.value);">  La verdad es que no se casi nada de ajax, empecé ayer a trastear, y no esto seguro ni si se puede llamara 2 funciones ajax @Oswaldo

Comment: pon el codigo de fetch_data_index_2.php

Comment: lo he metido en la pregunta @n00bz

Comment: prueba a hacer antes del $.ajax en la linea  de arriba pero dentro de la funcion un console.log(val_2) y nos dices si muestra algo, yo lo que creo es que no se esta cogiendo el valor del formulario

Comment: Además de lo que dice @KeTeMeTo, haz un `console.log` al `response`

Comment: Tienes razón, he mirado en la consola y me devuelve undefined, voy a añadir en el enunciado de donde cojo el valor val_2. @KeTeMeTo

Comment: si añadelo y te pongo como hacerlo, @DaxTter77 si falla en la primera linea, y esta en modo desarrollo el response del ajax sera el codigo del error que es el que ha descrito

Comment: Cuando le hago un console log al reponse me devuelve lo siguiente: (index):70 Uncaught ReferenceError: response is not defined
    at ajax_call_2 ((index):70)
    at HTMLTableRowElement.onchange ((index):100) -@DaxTter77 @KeTeMeTo

Comment: Soluciona primero el hecho de que el dato llega como undefined a ver

Comment: ea el error.... xd y que value tiene el tr con id= select edificios ? porque el primero te funciona porque es un select y el value es la opcion del select que tienes seleccionada pero el tr no tiene ningun value, prueba a poner <tr id="select_edificios" value="prueba" onchange="ajax_call_2(this.value);"> y en el console.log te deberia devolver prueba

Comment: Sigue dándome undefined. Pero creo que ya se por qué. Las variables this.value vienen de un select de un formulario, la única diferencia entre uno y otro es que el primer value (el que funciona) coge el valor del primer select (que es el que recoge los datos directamente desde PHP) pero el segundo lo coge del segundo select (el segundo select es el que se está ejecutando en AJAX). Alomejor el val_2 no lo coge porque no ve ninguno. @KeTeMeTo

Comment: La cuestión es esa que le estás pidiendo valor a un elemento que no lo da, porque no tiene como tal un valor

Comment: el val_2 no lo coge porque la funcion la ejecuta en un onchange() de un tr el cual no tiene value, a no ser que lo definas tu por otro lado es que no se la estructura, si es una celda o es texto dentro del tr, seria this.innerHtml o algo asi seria cuestion de ver mas codigo

Comment: Si sustitullo el tr por un select, si que me coge la variabe val_2 por consola.  <select id="select_edificios" value="prueba" onchange="ajax_call_2(this.value);"> -@KeTeMeTo @DaxTter77

Comment: Y sí te da el resultado esperado?

Comment: claro eso mismo te estoy diciendo que el tr es una fila y a no ser que definas tu el value del tr por medio de js en la linea html que tu has puesto no tiene value alguno y por eso da undefined

Comment: Ya me funciona, ha sido sustituir el tr por un select y me lo coge, ponlo como respuesta y te la marco como buena :3  Muchísias gracias a los dos, soy un negado para js y me habéis ayudado mucho -@KeTeMeTo @DaxTter77

Comment: Te doy el privilegio @KeTeMeTo escribe la respuesta, detallada y explicada. Javier que vayas bien en tu proyecto, saludos!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error es que el `tr` no tiene un `value` definido, puedes arreglar este fallo definiendo el `value` con js o bien simplemente cambiando a una etiqueta `select` como haces en la otra llamada a ajax
Cambia:

```
<tr id="select_edificios" onchange="ajax_call_2(this.value);">
```

por:

```
<select id="select_edificios" onchange="ajax_call_2(this.value);">
```

Un saludo